# Unable to set state on handleOnSuccess method- react-plaid-link integration

Tags: reactjs

I am having issues with react-plaid-link integration.  I am unable to setState of the variables coming back in the handleOnSuccess method. The accounts and token values are null inspite of setting the variables.
I used the following github code for reference. https://github.com/pbernasconi/react-plaid-link
Can someone please help me with this issue.
App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PlaidLink from "react-plaid-link";
import Accounts from "./components/Accounts";
import util from "./components/util";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    publicToken: 0,
    accounts: [],
    pageIndex:1,
    displayPlaid: true,
    displayAccounts: false,
    error:"",
    base_url:"http://localhost:8080/"
  };
  handleOnSuccess = (token, metadata) => {
    this.setState({

      publicToken: token,
      accounts: metadata,
      displayPlaid: false,
      displayAccounts: true

    });
  }
  render() {
    if(this.state.displayPlaid === true){
      return (
        <PlaidLink
          clientName="Plaid Client"
          env="sandbox"
          product={["auth", "transactions"]}
          publicKey="614be98f819e9bd8d0db9abec1c08a"
          className="some-class-name"
          apiVersion="v2"
          onSuccess={this.handleOnSuccess}
          onExit={this.handleOnExit}
          onEvent={this.handleOnEvent}
          onLoad={this.handleOnLoad}
        >
          Open Plaid Link button
        </PlaidLink>
      );
    } else {
      return(
        <Accounts accounts={this.state.accounts} />
      );
    }
  }
Accounts.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import TableStyle from '../css/Accounts.css';
import {Table} from 'reactstrap';
class Accounts extends Component {
render() {
// const {
//   accounts
//  } = this.props;
console.log(this.state.accounts);
return (

  <React.Fragment>
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <Table striped>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Account_id</th>
              <th scope="col">Balance</th>
              <th scope="col">Official name</th>
              <th scope="col">Sub type</th>
              <th scope="col">Type</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              this.props.accounts.map(account => {
              return (
                <tr key ={account.account_id}>
                  <td>{account.account_id}</td>
                  <td>{account.balances.current}</td>
                  <td>{account.name}</td>
                  <td>{account.subtype}</td>
                  <td>{account.type}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

}
}

export default Accounts;

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfjhA.png)You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleOnSuccess and pass it to onSuccess, this will be undefined when the function is actually called so you need to write below code in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

state = {
   publicToken: 0,
   accounts: [],
   pageIndex:1,
   displayPlaid: true,
   displayAccounts: false,
   error:"",
   base_url:"http://localhost:8080/"
};
this.handleOnSuccess = this.handleOnSuccess.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at my code.  I was thinking the arrow syntax should fix the issue. But I think I was wrong.  I made the changes suggested by you but I am still not able to get the values assigned in the state. I attached the Accounts.js code in the original post to make it clear. Please let me know if you got a chance to check this. Thanks again for your time.